# Why scrolling position change after Focus the input?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a editable text 
when i click in the text the `div` change into input keeping the text 
my problem is when i click into the text the `div` change into input but scroll position change.

**Jquery code:**

```
$('.content-comment').click(function(){
    $('.content-comment').hide();
    $('.content-comment-input').show();
    $('.content-comment-input').val($(this).text());
    $('.content-comment-input').focus();
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="comment-c">
      <div class="user-pic-c ></div>
      <div class="elements-comment">
           <div class="content-comment clear"><?php echo $k['test']; ?></div>
           <input class="content-comment-input" type="text" value="" style="display:none;">
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just find out the `width, padding, margins, borders` and calculate the height then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple because you change input value, so the position on your input will be changed. if you comment below line I assume it's work fine.

```
$('.content-comment').click(function(){
    $('.content-comment').hide();
    $('.content-comment-input').show();
    //$('.content-comment-input').val($(this).text());
    $('.content-comment-input').focus();
});
```